# DataFrame.sortlevel key

Tags: pandas

Is there a way to pass a `key` function (like `sorted` takes) to the `DataFrame.sortlevel` method in Pandas?

My issue is that I am using tuples for my index and I want to specify how they should be sorted relative to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement this as following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(*arrays), names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 20, 8), index=index)

keyfunc = lambda x:x[::-1]

key = map(keyfunc, s.index.get_level_values(0))
index = np.argsort(key)
s.take(index)
```

output:

```
first  second
foo    one        0
       two        3
bar    one        9
       two        8
qux    one        4
       two       12
baz    one       11
       two        1
dtype: int64
```